# Command prompt shows pip instlled to python 3.7 & python shows default 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When i type python in command prompt it shows 3.8 default location and pip to 3.7 due to which i am not able to import any function in command prompt. Pip install packagename work but pin - m install packagename says pip is not installed. I am facing lots of issues due to it in command prompt. My idle is 3.7 only and python 3.8 shows as hard disk file. I am facing a lot of issues due to it. Please suggest me way to fix so i can do all stuff in python.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling all python versions and reinstalling?

Comment: Sir i can't do that a lot of package is instlled

Comment: And sir my instlled program list shows only python 3.7 instlled but when i run py -0 in command prompt, I get two different versions of python in which 3.8 is by default

Comment: What operating system do you use, because if you use Command Prompt or CMD you are in windows, but windows does not take the `-m` argument with `pip` did you rather mean terminal. If yes please change it to terminal to avoid problems to people referring to this question or answering it.